# IntelliJ does not sort Kotlin imports according to ktlint's expectations

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When I select Code → Optimize Imports or Code → Reformat Code, the IntelliJ *does* optimize and sort imports, but even though I am using code style settings from Kotlin code style, the imports are not sorted in lexicographic order (not entirely at least). For example, this is the output produced:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson
import io.kotlintest.assertSoftly
import io.kotlintest.matchers.types.shouldBeNull
import io.kotlintest.shouldBe
import io.kotlintest.specs.ShouldSpec
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language
import java.time.Instant // This should not be at the bottom!!!
```

while this is what expected by [ktlint](https://ktlint.github.io/):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson
import io.kotlintest.assertSoftly
import io.kotlintest.matchers.types.shouldBeNull
import io.kotlintest.shouldBe
import io.kotlintest.specs.ShouldSpec
import java.time.Instant // should be here instead
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language
```

In other words, it seems the formatter always puts imports from `java.*` package at the bottom no matter what. Is there a way to make it be in line with what ktlint expects (and what would actually constitute lexicographic order)? Any hidden option I am missing or something?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) with the Kotlin plugin version 1.3.61-release-IJ2019.3-1. Version of ktlint is 0.36.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug/missing functionality in the Kotlin IDEA plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10974. Please vote.

Comment: It looks like the import layout feature is slated for Kotlin 1.4, the rule can be disabled via `.editorconfig` in a section like `[*.{kt,kts}]` with a configuration rule like `disabled_rules=import-ordering`.

Comment: Maybe someone needs this shortcut:  CTRL+ALT+O https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142468/Optimize-import-does-not-follow-the-set-order#focus=Comments-27-1039889.0-0

Answer (score 12):

You can change IntelliJ's import order for Kotlin to satisfy `ktlint`:

In `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin` you can change `Import Layout` by removing everything except `import all other imports` from the list:

#### Before:

[image: Settings before]

#### After:

[image: Settings after]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Obviously, when I asked this question, there was no such feature in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this in **2023**:

1. In 2020-06-20, ktlint [introduced an option](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/pull/749) to support intellij import alias rule
2. No longer need to tweak `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin`
3. You may also check out the import-layouts configuration guide [here](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/0.49.1/rules/configuration-ktlint/#import-layouts)

#### Usage

In your `.editorconfig` file:

```
[*.{kt,kts}]
ij_kotlin_imports_layout = *,java.**,javax.**,kotlin.**,^
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is manually removing all imports and then reimporting each import.

Comment: not a best practice and easy thing, but helps